# Trazer resultado do banco e colocar em uma lista para poder usar com variáveis

Tags: python, lista, arraylist, sqlite3, fetchall

Estou trabalhando com Python 3.7.

Estou tentando definir variáveis com dados de uma lista[], os valores da lista[] é resultado vindo do banco, mas está dando erro.

Código:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db/dataBase.db')  
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from configs")

lista = []
lista = cursor.fetchall()

id = lista[0]
valorOrdem = lista[1]
tipoOrdem = lista[2]
qtdOrdens = lista[3]
...

cursor.close
conn.close
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Ocorreu uma exceção: IndexError
list index out of range
```

Sei que este erro é pq estou tentando acessar um campo que não existe na lista[].

Não estou conseguindo distribuir o resultado do banco na lista[].
Preciso definir as variáveis com os valores da lista[0], lista[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h07s.png), lista[2]...

Segue o resultado que retorna do banco (está correto os dados):

```
0:(1, 2.0, 0, 3, 1, 5.0, 0, 1, 10.0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, ...)
len():1
```

Segue o print retorno do banco na lista[] e o erro quando tento setar a variável valorOrdem com o campo lista[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h07s.png):

[image: Erro]

Comment: Dê uma olhada na imagem na linha acima de *special variables* `[(1, 2.0, 0, 3, 1, 5.0, 0, 1, 10.0,...]` . Sua lista é composta por uma tupla de valores. Se essa consulta retornar apenas uma única linha faça `lista = cursor.fetchall()[0]`

Comment: Obrigado. Resolveu para essa consulta que retorna apenas uma linha do banco de dados, mas quando retornar mais de uma linha como eu poderia fazer ? Vou cair no mesmo problema descrito na postagem.

Comment: Cada tupla retornada por `fetchall()` é uma linha da tabela então crie [um laço de iteração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20iterar) e trabalhe com cada linha da tabela individualmente.

Comment: Tem gente que transforma o resultado de fetchall() numa array do pandas/numpy. Depende muito

Comment: Tentei fechar a pergunta com a resposta do @AugustoVasques, mas não pude por estar em um comentário. Mas resolveu o problema. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Interpretando os comentários anexados a pergunta...

Dê uma olhada na imagem, na linha acima de special variables:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sua lista é composta por uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) de valores.
Se essa consulta retornar apenas uma única linha faça:

```
lista = cursor.fetchall()[0]
```

No seu exemplo:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db/dataBase.db')  
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from configs")    

lista = cursor.fetchall()[0]              #Aqui pega a primeira tupla retornada pela consulta

id = lista[0]
valorOrdem = lista[1]
tipoOrdem = lista[2]
qtdOrdens = lista[3]
...

cursor.close
conn.close
```

Cada *tupla* retornada por [fetchall()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) é uma linha da tabela cujo a consulta foi realizada então crie um laço de iteração[[for](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)/[while]](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) e trabalhe com cada linha da tabela individualmente:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db/dataBase.db')  
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from testes")

for linha in cursor.fetchall():
      ...realize alguma alguma ação...
```

Ou então lendo alguma tabela com Pandas, segundo essa [resposta dada no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36029761/11379709):

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

cnx = sqlite3.connect('file.db')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name", cnx)
```